# What does $\overline{z}\mathbb{1}$ and $\underline{z}\mathbb{1}$ mean?

Tags: game-theory

I'm working on some paper concerning auction analysis. I have trouble with understanding what is the meaning of symbols:

$\overline{z}\mathbb{1}$ and  $\underline{z}\mathbb{1}$

[image]

Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: What book/article is this from?

Comment: http://econpapers.repec.org/bookchap/eeegamchp/1-08.htm

Comment: Chapter 08 in Handbook of Game Theory with Economic Applications, 1992, vol. 1, pp 227-279 from Elsevier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be from Robert Wilson, [Strategic Analysis of Auctions](http://faculty-gsb.stanford.edu/wilson/PDF/Auctions/Strategic%20analysis%20of%20auctions.pdf).  (Surprisingly you can find this by just Googling the phrase "indicate nature's choice".)  The passage here is on p. 6 of the linked pdf.

I believe $\underline{z}$ and $\overline{z}$ are just scalars, and $\mathbb{1}$ is the vector of all 1s.  Furthermore $\le$ is being used on vectors to mean componentwise inequality: that is, $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \le (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)$ is defined to mean $x_i \le y_i$ for $1, 2, \cdots, n$.    So the cell $Z =  \{ z \: | \: \underline{z} \mathbb{1} \le z \le \overline{z} \mathbb{1} \}$ is just the set of vectors $z$ where every element is between $\underline{z}$ and $\overline{z}$.